# What's the largest REG_SZ value that Regedit can edit?

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

I came across a large string value (REG_SZ) in the Registry and I want to copy it. As I double clicked the value, the textbox was empty.

What is the largest REG_SZ value that Regedit can edit in its textbox?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The largest string that can be displayed in the Regedit's textbox has a length of 43679. beginning with a length of 43680, the textbox will appear to be empty. (Windows 10 21H1, if that matters).

And I say "appear", because the value is actually still there. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in order to copy it into the clipboard. And you can also copy a text into the clipboard and paste it back to Regedit and accept it.

Comment: +1 because I never knew I wanted to know this. xD Good question with great answer. :)

Comment: 43680/dec = 0xAAA0/hex, that is an odd limitation!?  ;-) Are we in BCD-country?

Comment: If the value is still there then it may be a display limitation on the width of the text passed to the API that the edit control uses to paint.

Comment: @Hannu 43680*3+32 = 2^17. Not sure why that might be the limit (perhaps something related to multi byte encodings with 3 bytes per character?), but feels closer to the truth than 0xAAA0.

Comment: That's a really odd limitation.  The usual textbox limit on Windows is 65535 characters.

Comment: @Mark: yes, and typically that's a maximum. But in this case, it just becomes invisible.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Windows is almost exclusively UTF-16. A 3-byte encoding doesn’t make sense. Especially considering the registry was created at the time when everyone thought UCS-2 (UTF-16 with no surrogates) was as much as we needed. Something related to rendering cavas size would make more sense IMO. Especially if the width goes “negative” through overflow.

Comment: Looking at this again; three bytes per character -> stored as Two-byte strings with a NUL terminator as third byte?  But then, at least some of 0100, 0200 and so on "unicodes" *has* actual characters, so would not be possible in such storage (second byte NUL).  **Linux: Hold CTRL+SHIFT and hit u, then type the code and hit ENTER. Windows: Type the code, hold ALT and hit x.**  (code in HEX!)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will not always work, since it does not work on this two keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\OneSettings\TargetingAttributes
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsSelfHost\OneSettings\TargetingAttributesVerified
```

Both values are multi-line very long texts (>60000 each), just like this small  reduced sample pattern:

```
{
  "Version": ...
  "SchemaVersion": ...
  ...
}
```

But i can confirm that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works, it copy the very long multi-line value perfectly.

But any attempt to put a new multi-line value (for a simple edit of a small part) does not work, no matter how long or short it is, it will only take/accept (write) the first line of the text.

So using REGEDIT to edit such kind of values looks like it is not an option.

Also tried:

- If i export the branch to a (.reg) file, edit the text inside the (.reg) file and try to re-import (double clicking) and refresh (with <kbd>F5</kbd> key), such values are not updated.
- If i export the branch to a (.reg) file, delete the key, try to re-import (double clicking) and refresh (with F5 key), such keys are not imported (but the message says all keys were imported).
- I also had tested with a short multi-line value, same results, no way to paste it, only accepted first line, also ignored if inside a (.reg) file, etc.

The key type is somehow weird, it is REG_SZ, not REG_MULTI_SZ.

That is getting me really madness, how is it possible to put/edit such values when they are multi-line in a REG_SZ type key is something i do not know.

Thanks anyway, at least i can read/copy them.

Comment: This looks like more of a comment to the existing answer than an answer in its own right.